# Как добавить максимальное значение для прогресс бара

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я использую ProgressBar.js 0.9.0 для вывода круглого прогрессбара

инициализация происходит вот таким способом

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


$('.progress').each(function(index, element) {
    index = index+1;
    $(element).attr('id','progress'+index);
});
});


window.onload = function onLoad() {

var circle1 = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress1', {
    color: '#14AA18', 
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'easeInOut',        
        strokeWidth: 10, 
    trailWidth: 10, 
    trailColor: '#eee', 
});
circle1.animate($('#progress1').attr('data-online')/100);

};
```

в этом блоке появляется зеленый круг при загрузке 100 и пол круга при загрузке 50 и т.д..

```
 <div class="progress" data-online="100"></div>
```

Проблема в том что если значение больше чем 100, то круг делает еще один оборот и уже уменьшается, а не увеличивается.

Как сделать что бы при значении data-online больше 100 прогресс бар останавливался на 100, а не к примеру на 190. Видел max-data-online но как его внедрить я не понимаю...

Вот ссылка на песочницу где можно увидеть наглядно https://jsfiddle.net/l2banners/aoc37b2b/

Comment: `Видел max-data-online но как его внедрить я не понимаю.` - что значит "как его внедрить"?

Comment: Как заставить его работать, я пробовал прописывать  <div class="progress" data-online="100" max-data-online="100"></div> но нечего не изменилось, его же надо как-то в js добавить что бы работало...

Comment: ааа. я кажется понял, что вы хотите вместо `circle1.animate($('#progress1').attr('data-online')/100);` написать `circle1.animate($('#progress1').attr('data-online')/$('#progress1').attr('data-max-online'));`.... мм?

Comment: Не, я так пробовал тоже самое получается...

Comment: ну так максимуму 100 напишите.....или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Значение data-online может быть выше data-‌​max-online и мне надо в в таких случаях что бы значение фиксировалось на максимуме, так как он генерируется автоматически я не могу каждый раз его в ручную корректировать...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/je654p6k/1/   оно?

Comment: Да, это похоже именно то что надо, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function onLoad() {

   var circle1 = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress1', {
     color: '#14AA18', 
     duration: 3000,
     easing: 'easeInOut',        
     strokeWidth: 10, 
     trailWidth: 10, 
     trailColor: '#eee', 
   });
   circle1.animate(Math.min($('#progress1').attr('data-online')/100, 1));
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это именно то что надо и теперь все работает так как надо, предыдущее решение тоже было неплохое, но в нем есть одна проблема.